# HoughCircles circle detection not working?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, detection

I have been trying to write a program that can detect circles on my screen.

[This is my screen before code processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUzFw.png)

As you can see on the image, there are three circles that the code should detect. I am using HoughCircles function from OpenCV library to achieve this task. My code is below.

```
ss = gui.screenshot()

img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(ss), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
output = img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

if circles is not None:
    print("circles found", len(circles))

    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    for (x, y, r) in circles:

        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([gray, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow("output", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am first taking screenshot of my screen. Then, I convert it to use it for opencv.

However, this code does not detect any circles for the  screenshot shown in the first picture. I know this because when ran, my program does not print "circles found". Moreover, to show that I have been taking screenshots and transforming them to grayscale properly, I have this image taken from the last two lines of my code.

[picture in a gray scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty4m8.png)

To show that my code works with other circle images, here is a picture of a regular circle:

[before detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw5lK.png)

[after detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Ikn.png)

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried playing with the numbers `1.2`, `100`? This is python signature of that function `circles = cv.HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]`, so your `dp` is 1.2 and your `minDist` is 100 but the also is also quite sensitive to `param1` and `param2`.  Also, under the hood, houghcircle uses canny edge detector. You need to be able to see crisp circles with canny first, and use the parameters you use there for `param1` and `param2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the parameters of houghCircles that works for me. You should also consider running a gaussian blur over the image before trying to find the circles.

[image]

I'm not a huge fan of houghCircles. I find it to be really finicky and I don't like how much of what it does is hidden inside the function. It makes tuning it mostly trial-and-error. These parameters work for this particular image, but I wouldn't count on this continuing to work under different lighting conditions or for different colors.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("spheres.png");

# grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0);

# circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp = 1, minDist = 100, param1=65, param2=20, minRadius=20, maxRadius=50)

# draw circles
if circles is not None:
    # round to ints
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles));
    for circle in circles[0, :]:
        # unpack and draw
        x, y, radius = circle;
        center = (x,y);
        cv2.circle(img, center, radius, (255, 0, 255), 3);

# show
cv2.imshow("Image", img);
cv2.imshow("Gray", gray);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thank you! The above code has proven successful for my intended purpose of this code. However, when it comes to doing len(circles), it seems like the function outputs 1 instead of 3. The code is still able to detect the 3 circles, but the length remains 1. Any ideas of why it could be?

Comment: it's kinda annoying. Some of Opencv's functions double wrap the return list. You have to do len(circles[0]). However, if no circles are returned then it actually returns None so you have to check for that first.

Comment: @Jeremy if the answer helped you solve your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative solution to detect the circles without using the Hough Transform. As your input image has a very distinct **blue hue** to the blobs of interest, you can try to create a segmentation mask based on their `HSV` values. Then, detect `contours` and **approximate** each `contour` using a circle. The last step can be implemented using the `cv2.minEnclosingCircle`, which, as its name suggest, can compute the **Minimum Enclosing Circle** of a `contour`.

Let's see the code:

```
# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "XUzFw.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)
# Create a deep copy of the input for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert the image to the HSV color space:
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Set the HSV values:
lowRange = np.array([78, 0, 158])
uppRange = np.array([125, 255, 255])

# Create the HSV mask
mask = cv2.inRange(hsvImage, lowRange, uppRange)
```

This generates the following segmentation mask:

[image]

As you can see, the only blobs that remain are the circles. Now, let's compute the `contours` and find the **minimum enclosing circle**:

```
# Find the circle blobs on the binary mask:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Use a list to store the center and radius of the target circles:
detectedCircles = []

# Look for the outer contours:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Approximate the contour to a circle:
    (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)

    # Compute the center and radius:
    center = (int(x), int(y))
    radius = int(radius)

    # Draw the circles:
    cv2.circle(inputImageCopy, center, radius, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # Store the center and radius:
    detectedCircles.append([center, radius])

# Let's see the results:
cv2.namedWindow("Circles", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Circles", inputImageCopy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result of the detection:

[image]

Additionally, you can check out the data stored in the `detectedCircles` list:

```
# Check out the detected circles:
for i in range(len(detectedCircles)):
    # Get circle data:
    center, r = detectedCircles[i]
    # Print it:
    print("i: "+str(i)+" x: "+str(center[0])+" y: "+str(center[1])+" r: "+str(r))
```

Which yields:

```
i: 0 x: 395 y: 391 r: 35
i: 1 x: 221 y: 391 r: 36
i: 2 x: 567 y: 304 r: 35
```

Comment: thank you for the help. It seems like your code is far more accurate than the previous solution. However, time is also a factor for my project, so I want the least amount of computing time possible. Therefore, for my scenario, the other solution would be better.